# Automated download from multiple URLs, handling Feedback Dialog / cookies

Tags: r, cookies, download, rcurl

I try to bulk download CORINE Landcover zip-files from [this site](http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/clc-2006-vector-data-version-2) but I think the interconnected feedback survey window from Google Analytics is making troubles here.. Is there some sort of Curl handler for these issues?

I viewed the cookie in sqlite manager, these are the entries: baseDomain = "europa.eu", name = "clc06_c133.zip", value = "sectors%3Denvironment", host = "www.eea.europa.eu",..
the cookie path is "C:\Users\Kay\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ckut8fjm.default\cookies.sqlite"

```
setwd("D:/GIS DataBase/CorineLC/")

mylist <- list(
clc06_1 <- "111 - Continuous urban fabric",
clc06_2 <- "112 - Discontinuous urban fabric",
clc06_3 <- "121 - Industrial or commercial units",
clc06_4 <- "122 - Road and rail networks and associated land",
clc06_5 <- "123 - Port areas",
clc06_6 <- "124 - Airports",
clc06_7 <- "131 - Mineral extraction sites",
clc06_8 <- "132 - Dump sites",
clc06_9 <- "133 - Construction sites",
clc06_10 <- "141 - Green urban areas",
clc06_11 <- "142 - Sport and leisure facilities",
clc06_12 <- "211 - Non-irrigated arable land",
clc06_13 <- "212 - Permanently irrigated land",
clc06_14 <- "213 - Rice fields",
clc06_15 <- "221 - Vineyards",
clc06_16 <- "222 - Fruit trees and berry plantations",
clc06_17 <- "223 - Olive groves",
clc06_18 <- "231 - Pastures",
clc06_19 <- "241 - Annual crops associated with permanent crops",
clc06_20 <- "242 - Complex cultivation patterns",
clc06_21 <- "243 - Land principally occupied by agriculture, with significant areas of natural vegetation",
clc06_22 <- "244 - Agro-forestry areas",
clc06_23 <- "311 - Broad-leaved forest",
clc06_24 <- "312 - Coniferous forest",
clc06_25 <- "313 - Mixed forest",
clc06_26 <- "321 - Natural grasslands",
clc06_27 <- "322 - Moors and heathland",
clc06_28 <- "323 - Sclerophyllous vegetation",
clc06_29 <- "324 - Transitional woodland-shrub",
clc06_30 <- "331 - Beaches, dunes, sands",
clc06_31 <- "332 - Bare rocks",
clc06_32 <- "333 - Sparsely vegetated areas",
clc06_33 <- "334 - Burnt areas",
clc06_34 <- "335 - Glaciers and perpetual snow",
clc06_35 <- "411 - Inland marshes",
clc06_36 <- "412 - Peat bogs",
clc06_37 <- "421 - Salt marshes",
clc06_38 <- "422 - Salines",
clc06_39 <- "423 - Intertidal flats",
clc06_40 <- "511 - Water courses",
clc06_41 <- "512 - Water bodies",
clc06_42 <- "521 - Coastal lagoons",
clc06_43 <- "522 - Estuaries",
clc06_44 <- "523 - Sea and ocean")

# extract the CLC codes which are the 3-digit number in the string:
foo1 <- function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, " - "))[[1]]
# and the names
foo2 <- function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, " - "))[[2]]

codes <- sapply(mylist, foo1, simplify = T)
names <- sapply(mylist, foo2, simplify = T)

# make urls
names_url <- gsub(",", "",  gsub("\\s", "-", names))
dl_url <- paste0("http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/clc-2006-vector-data-version-2/",
                 codes, "-", names_url, "/clc06_c", codes, ".zip/at_download/file")

# get zip file names
get_zip_name <- function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, "/"))[grep(".zip", unlist(strsplit(x, "/")))]

# function to plug into sapply
dl_url_to_zip <- function(x) download.file(x, dest = get_zip_name(x))

# gives http status 404!
sapply(dl_url, dl_url_to_zip)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `httr` package:

```
require(httr)
require(XML)

response <- GET("http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/clc-2006-vector-data-version-2")
doc <- htmlParse(content(response,as="text"))
files <- xpathSApply(doc,'//*/a[contains(@href,"http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/clc-2006-vector-data-version-2/")]/@href')
files <- files[-c(1,47:50)]

files[10]
#href 
#"http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/clc-2006-vector-data-version-2/141-green-urban-areas/clc06_c141.zip/at_download/file" 
dl_url[10]
#[1] "http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/clc-2006-vector-data-version-2/141-Green-urban-areas/clc06_c141.zip/at_download/file"
```

Notice you had capitals `Green-urban-areas` instead of `green-urban-areas`

```
response <- GET(files[10])
writeBin(content(response),'test.zip')
```

I started with `httr` package as I assumed we might need cookies. In fact

```
download.file(files[10],'test.zip',mode="wb")
```

would work equally as well. The error in your original code is the capitalisation.

Comment: With `htmlParse()` you mean `htmlParse::XML` ? When loading the package and using the function I get an error message: `Error in htmlParse(content(response, as = "text")) : File`. When downloading  manually I have this Feedback Survey Form requiring 2 check boxes to be ticked (those inputs are saved in a cookie I believe) - does your approach account for this?

Comment: Darn, my code was in fact working - it was the uppercase names!! However, using XML as you did is much more elegant and I'd wish to get it to work! Would this then also work for all files (several items are displayed on 4 seperate sites)?

Comment: The XML package is required I have added this. I assumed wrongly httr depended on it.

Comment: I still get the error with `htmlParse()`.. And, when I downloaded with `download.file()` the files had the appropiate size but seem to be malformed as unzipping them doesn't work..

Comment: `htmlParse` works for me on a seperate linux and windows box. On a windows box you may need to add `mode = 'wb'` to `download.file`. Check you have a recent version of `XML`.

Comment: Many thanks! I just did `doc <- htmlParse("http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/clc-2006-vector-data-version-2")
urls <- xpathSApply(doc,'//*/a[contains(@href,"http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/clc-2006-vector-data-version-2/")]/@href')`and this works perfectly!